# JavaScript: remove all but 1 key from an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object and I want to remove all values except the one that matches a particular key. For example, I could do this:

```
function remove(obj, key) {
  var value = obj[key]
  var ret = {}
  ret[key] = obj[key]
  obj = ret
}
```

Or I could iterate:

```
for (var k in obj) {
  if (k != key) {
    delete obj[k]
  }
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way.  Creating a temporary variable and iterating over the entire object both seem unnecessary.  My initial attempt was:

```
obj = {
  key: obj[key]
}
```

But that resulted in an object with a key of `key`.

Comment: Try `[key]: obj[key]`. You need a computed property, not a literal property here.

Comment: @saniales thats what I tried initially and it didn't work.  read the end of the question

Comment: is key a variable?

Comment: @Xufox that worked.  post as an answer please

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed achieve what you described without using temporary variables.

```
function remove(obj, key) {
  return Object.assign({}, { [key] : obj[key]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new object with [key]:obj[key].

```js
var obj = {
 "a":1,
 "b":2
};
var key = "a";

function filterByKey(object, key) {
    return Object.create({[key]:obj[key]});
}
function filterByKey2(object, key) {
    return {[key]:obj[key]};
}
console.log(filterByKey(obj, key));
console.log(filterByKey2(obj, key));
```